# Gulp build does not install dependencies automatically?

Tags: node.js, build, dependencies, npm, gulp

I use gulp to build my javascript application. I have some dependencies declared in the `package.json` file, for example:

```
"dependencies": {
  "flux": "^2.0.1",
  "keymirror": "~0.1.0",
  "object-assign": "^1.0.0",
  "react": "^0.13.1",
  "dropzone": "^4.0.1",
  "lodash": "^3.6.0"
}
```

When I run gulp build, it always prompt me some dependency cannot be found unless I manually run `npm install lodash` for example.

Is there a way to have gulp run `npm install` automatically?

Comment: I bet you could, but it would likely be the roundabout way. You can install all your dependencies with a simple `npm install`, and it just will install those which aren't there, so the most easiest would be `npm install && gulp build` on your shell to make sure it's executed before you run gulp

Comment: yes that's what I am doing now :-)

Comment: If you have yet to run `npm install`, how would you have gulp installed locally before you run gulp (unless it's installed globally, which is don't think is very common)? For me, I would probably just use `npm install` then use `postinstall` script to run gulp.

Comment: Use the gulp-install package from npm (see @halogner's answer below)

Answer (score 43):

Run `npm install --save-dev` command to resolve all dependencies.

Here is link to documentation with `--save-dev` parameter description: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 6):

1. You require to have package.json on the root level.
2. Then once you have to run npm install for all the dependencies with --saveDev(development dependencies) or --save(project level dependencies).
3. Once this is done, for the next time only run npm install command will install dependent dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

[gulp-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-install) would help for your issue. Go to [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) (node package manager) and search for "gulp-install".

The node plugin `gulp-install` automatically installs packages/dependencies for npm, bower, tsd, and pip. The relative configurations must be found in the gulp file stream.

[Example Usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-install#usage):

In your gulpfile.js:

```
var install = require("gulp-install");

gulp.src(["./package.json", "./bower.json"])
  .pipe(install());
```

Comment: This answers the question, which is about running npm install from gulp, not about updating the package.json file when installing using npm.

Comment: does this install dev dependencies as well?